# springfox 2.2.3 snapshot dependencies adding failed because of missing nexus-maven-repository-index.properties

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, swagger-2.0, springfox, ojo

I setup my project with springfox 2.2.3 snapshot version in IDEA 14 with gradle. I follow instruction [2.1.1. Gradle Snapshot](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/). I failed with error that maven repository cannot be indexed and see exception in IDEA's log:

```
WARN -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Failed to update Maven indices for: [com.intellij.util.CachedValueImpl@a1d13c] http://oss.jfrog.org/simple/oss-snapshot-local/io/springfox
```

org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerIndexerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Resource nexus-maven-repository-index.properties does not exist

I tried both repositories and both failed:

- http://oss.jfrog.org/simple/oss-snapshot-local/io/springfox/
- http://oss.jfrog.org/oss-snapshot-local/io/springfox/

Could anyone have any idea how to fix the issue?

I tried to download dependencies manually and put them in my local .m2 directory and setup in gradle `mavenLocal()` instead of `maven {url ...}` but my attempt failed with IDEA's warning on Gradle refresh operation:

```
Warning:<i><b>project ':data-service': Web Facets/Artifacts will not be configured</b>
Details: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':data-service:runtime'.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.2.3-SNAPSHOT.
Required by:
parseq:data-service:2.4.0 alpha</i>
```

Now I think that should also manually add transitive dependencies for springfox package. But it looks ugly and I think I should not go this way.

Does anyone has idea what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found issues with dependency donwloading:
 * when I work from corporate network I have SSL certificate issue
 * initially I added `maven { url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/' }` into `buildscript {...}` section, I changed it to `repositories {...}` and fixed the issue
 * also I updated my gradle to 2.4 version (but it didn't help)

Now my starting issue is fixed.